# PhoneGap File Upload (other then images) using file transfer

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

i have a a sequence of task to do with the phoneGap.
one is that i have to select the file from library/storage of the device and then upload to server.

With the reference from the documentation form the phoneGap site [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#) i found somethings related to the image upload and i successfully able to run that as well, but

1. the problem is that when i browse the device it only shows the image files, how can i select the other files??  here is the code

   ```
   function getImage() 
   {
       // Retrieve image file location from specified source
       navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) 
                                   {
                                   alert('get picture failed');
                                   },{
                                   quality: 50, 
                                   destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                   sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY

                                   });

   }
   ```
2. selection and uploading succesfull only in case if selection is made from photo library , the app crashes when selection using file manager ,, how to handle this ??

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Refer this one http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/file-chooser-dialog-for-phonegap-application/ it will helpfull....

Comment: i have tried this but there is few points that i am unable to solve.... can you guide me through that @Aravinth

Comment: yes tell me what issue you have..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [file chooser plugin](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser) to pick a file (android only), and then upload it